# How do I access a database in Unity?

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

I am trying to POST data to my database in Unity and it doesn't seem to be working. I know it is probably a very stupid mistake as I do have little knowledge in this field.

The C# script I have:

```html
   void logIn(string test) {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("action","send");
        form.AddField("var1",test);
        string url = "http://www.prizechief.com/unitycon.php";
        WWW w = new WWW(url, form);
        
    }

    void Start() {
        string sample = "Works";
        logIn(sample);
        

    }
```

My PHP code

```html
<?php
 $con = @mysqli_connect("server","un","pass", "db") or die("Could not connect " . mysqli_connect_error() . "Please try again later.");
 
 $var1 = $_GET['var1'];
 echo $var1;
 
 mysqli_Query($con,"INSERT INTO test (var) VALUE ('$var1')");
?>
```

Also, a hint on how to use GET to receive information would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe including more detail about WHY it's not working would be helpful.

Comment: @CharlieFish If I knew why it wasn't working, I wouldn't have posted this

Comment: Yes but saying "I am trying to POST data to my database in Unity and it doesn't seem to be working." isn't helpful. How isn't it working? Is it giving you an error? What happens when you try to post data? Please include how it isn't working. Expected result and current result etc.

Comment: Okay so the PHP script for posting data to my database is working 100%, but the C# script isn't nor is it giving any errors. @CharlieFish

Comment: Is your PHP script being called even when you run the C# script?

Comment: That's what I don't know @CharlieFish I don't really know about the WWW class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. That should do the WWW request and set `$_GET['var1']` = to `value1` in your PHP script. Now of course you will have to change that to your variable down the road. But just to test for now. If this doesn't work let me know what the debug logs print out.

```
void Start () {
    string url = "http://www.prizechief.com/unitycon.php?var1=value1";
    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www));
}

IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW www)
{
    yield return www;

    // check for errors
    if (www.error == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("WWW Ok!: " + www.data);
    } else {
        Debug.Log("WWW Error: "+ www.error);
    }    
}
```

**EDIT**

Remember to go into Edit > Player Settings > Editor and change the URL to your domain.

Comment: WWW Error: Rejected because no crossdomain.xml policy file was found
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<WaitForRequest>c__Iterator0:MoveNext() (at Assets/Scripts/login.cs:24)

Comment: Update: After playing around with it for a while, I managed to make it work. I went to Edit => Player Settings => Editor and changed the url to my domain. Thanks :D

Comment: Cool! Glad I could help. If you feel like my code helped please remember to accept the answer so other users who have the same issue can see it as well. Of course no need to but if it helped and you want to just for other users sake :) I will go in and make an edit to my answer to include that part now. Glad it works now!!